# How to get value of selected text by tag name, not id

Tags: jquery-selectors

I only have names of tags, no ids. Need to figure out a way to get text of selected dropdowns. This is the HTML:

```
<SELECT name="selectRightName">
<OPTION value="76" >1</OPTION>
<OPTION value="200" >2</OPTION>
<OPTION value="201" >3</OPTION>
<OPTION value="202" >4</OPTION>
<OPTION value="203" >5</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

By some reason this returns empty value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

alert(productName);
alert(selectRightName);
 $('select[name=selectRightName]').change(onSelectChange);
 $('select[name=selectLeftName]').change(onSelectChange);
```

});

function onSelectChange(){

```
var fselected = $('select[name=selectRightName] option:selected'); 
var sselected = $('select[name=selectLeftName] option:selected');
    alert(fselected + " " + sselected);
```

Comment: your casing is off, one is capitalized

Answer (score 1):

The attribute in your HTML starts with a capital S, but your selector isn't reflecting it, and attribute selectors are case-sensitive everywhere.

```
var fselected = $('select[name=SelectRightName] option:selected');
```

Also there's a stray `)` in your HTML, not sure what that's doing there but you should remove it.

Comment: fixed spelling issues, still does not work. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: @Alexica: Where are you triggering this selector? Is it part of a change event or is it on document ready? If it's on document ready, you may need to actually mark one of the options `selected` first.

Comment: function suppose to trigger upon changing value in dropdown, so part of change event. Here is the complete script:            $(document).ready(function(){
   
 alert(productName);
 alert(selectRightName);
  $('select[name=selectRightName]').change(onSelectChange);
     $('select[name=selectLeftName]').change(onSelectChange);
  
 });
 
 function onSelectChange(){
  
  var fselected = $('select[name=selectRightName] option:selected'); 
  var sselected = $('select[name=selectLeftName] option:selected');
      alert(fselected + " " + sselected);

Comment: how do you make code show in grey background in answers? It didn't let me add 4 spaces...

Comment: @Alexica: You should be putting that in your question as an edit.